# Chart controls for Angular 2+ (Steema controls)

Tags: teechart

Does Tee-chart provide chart controls for Angular2+?

Typescript plugin Link:
https://www.steema.com/files/public/teechart/html5/latest/demos/plugins/typescript/index.htm#ts_src

Cannot understand how helpful are plugins by tee chart and feasible for full fledged development.
Do they fully support angular 2+ chart controls now or any plans in future?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Steema is currently preparing modified typescipt files and examples for TeeChart with angular and expect to have them ready in the near future

Comment: Can you provide a small example of using the typescript plugin for using Tee chart library. I am using the script tag     <script src="http://steema.us/files/jscript/src/teechart.js" type="text/javascript"></script>  to use it currently but i want to know how to use it by importing it.What to install and what to import. Currently I have installed @types/teechart, is it correct?.

Comment: Hello, 
Sorry for the delay. I would like suggest you take a look in my example you find in this link: https://jsfiddle.net/ladyviolet86/q3agu4k7/. Also you can get the Teechart Javascript examples you find in Github. Here's the link: https://github.com/Steema/TeeChartJS/tree/master/demos
Thanks,